# TypeScript create new interface from existing interface and change type of all properties

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, typescript-generics

```js
interface UserFlags {
  isDev: boolean;
  isAdmin: boolean;
  isMod: boolean;
}

const flagPositions: FlagPositions<UserFlags> = {
  isDev: 0,
  isAdmin: 1,
  isMod: 2,
};
```

How would you implement `FlagPositions` so that it takes 1 generic parameter to an interface with type `{ [name: string]: boolean }` and require all the properties of the interface to be present in the new interface but be of type `number`?

I tried various methods using `keyof` but none worked.

Edit: I got this working after posting but I would like it to be an interface

```js
type FlagPositions<F> = {
  [K in keyof Required<F>]: number;
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `FlagPositions<T>` to be a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) whose keys are the same as `keyof T` but whose values are `number`.  You can write that like this:

```
type FlagPositions<T> = { [K in keyof T]: number };
```

And verify that it works as you want:

```
const flagPositions: FlagPositions<UserFlags> = {
    isDev: 0,
    isAdmin: 1,
    isMod: 2,
};
```

---

Note that it is not necessary to [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `T` to `{[name: string]: boolean}` or `Record<keyof T, boolean>`, but you can do so if you want:

```
type FlagPositions<T extends Record<keyof T, boolean>> =
    { [K in keyof T]: number };


declare const oops: FlagPositions<{ a: number }>; // error!
// ---------------------------->  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//   Types of property 'a' are incompatible.
```

---

You can't make `FlagPositions<T>` an `interface` because interfaces need to have keys known at compile time, and `T` is generic and can have all sorts of keys.  But once you have the `FlagPositions<UserFlags>` type which has known keys (they are `isDev`, `isAdmin`, and `isMod`), then you can make an `interface` extend *that*:

```
interface UserFlagPositions extends FlagPositions<UserFlags> { }

const u: UserFlagPositions = {
    isDev: 2,
    isAdmin: 1,
    isMod: 0
}
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=7#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgKoGdoDEA2cDm6yA3gLABQyVyw6AIhAG4BcyARgPYc4RwgDcFajXQBBACYBbUK07deAodVoBZDuNlcefQeQC+FCmACeABxS4CABQ7pgYYBxDoAPABVkEAB6QQ4ogBKEAgcUOIuANYQxhwwyG4ANOxaCgB8qcgAvEpUxMgA2gDSNCDIUTFxbgC6rCAArpJs0Mh6uhQhzmDIMHj4NnYOTuisln229o7OLhjYvegZmSQ5IgwsyAAMCcu0EtIgrACMW5TK6GoayABMx62G5OLBeFAoHehdXKbDyKP9E0MueTgtQaTSgLVS-GQAHooZ4oFBQgBCCgw5AAWgxmKx2JxuIyyAAfkTiSTiSjYVQ3GYIERYshTAjzFATMgAORwVnIODPEohSSmOAONg8AB0d1AkFgiBQMygP3Gg2cnh8ED8RHlA0mrllo3mJBad1eXTqrB1vV+iqIizIJyotFWrGu2zEUhkyCOzvOrHWFD0QA)

Comment: Thank you very much. Is it possible to convert it into an interface?

Comment: You can write `interface UserFlagPositions extends FlagPositions<UserFlags> {}`.  But you are changing the scope of the question, and any further scope change probably needs its own separate post

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. An interface was what I originally wanted however, since it works, everything is fine